# CV problem when compiling

Tags: cv

I try to compile my cv, using latex. My example is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, xcolor, bibentry, longtable}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{\bfseries\Huge MY NAME}
\author{\large{\textbf{\textit{15 Febbraio 2017}}}}
\date{}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.85\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}


\begin{filecontents}{mynew.bib}

@book{bnm,
title{mybook},
author={Myself, M. and Yourself, Y.},
publisher={Cambridge University Press},
address={Cambridge},
}

@article{myarticle,
title={The Title},
author={Right, M. and Left, D. and Up, L. and Down, D.},
journal={The journal},
volume={10},
pages={423--443},
}

@incollection{new,
author = {Right, L. and Left, D. and Up, P.},
title = {New title},
editor = {Red, A. and Blue, E.G. and Green, G.A.},
booktitle = {The Handbook of my world},
publisher = {Routledge},
address = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{1em}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
\footnotesize
My Department\\
My University\\
My Place
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[ht]{0.48\textwidth}
\footnotesize
Tel.: +12345678\\
Email: email@emaik.it\\
Web: https://sites.google.com/site/mine
\end{minipage}
\vspace{20pt}
\section*{Informazioni Anagrafiche}
Data di Nascita: 0X/0X/19XX\\[5pt]
Cittadinanza: Italiana

\section*{Posizione Accademica}

\section*{Posizioni di Visiting}
\section*{Incarichi Accademici}

\subsection*{\it First}

\subsection*{\it Second}

\subsection*{\it Third}

\section*{Istruzione}

\section*{Progetti di Ricerca}

\section*{Premi e Borse di Studio}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\nobibliography{mynew}
\section*{Pubblicazioni}
\subsection*{\it Monografie}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2014&\bibentry{mybook}\\ [5pt]
\end{longtable}

\subsection*{\it Capitoli di Libro}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2016& \bibentry{new}\\[5pt]
\end{longtable}

\subsection*{\it Lavori in riviste referate}
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2017&\bibentry{myarticle}\\[5pt]
\end{longtable}


\section*{Teaching (Last 5 years)}

\section*{References}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it, the bibentries do not appear in the file. Moreover, I get the following error message:

> Sorry, but "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\texify.exe"
>   did not succeed.
>
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
>   again:
>
> C:/Users/dario/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/texify.log
>
> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help

I tried to synchronize the texify file using my package manager (Miktex 2.9) but nothing happens. In addition if I try to compile again the file, I obtain the same error message and I cannot compile my tex unless I cancel all the auxiliary files I have in my folder.

Does someone know why this happens?

Thanks in advace,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a `=` in your bibliography. See the following entry for a corrected version:

```
@book{bnm,
title={mybook},
author={Myself, M. and Yourself, Y.},
publisher={Cambridge University Press},
address={Cambridge},
}
```

Then it compiles without errors.

Your second problem is solved by using the right key as follows:

```
\begin{longtable}{L!{\VRule}R}
2014&\bibentry{bnm}\\ [5pt]
\end{longtable}
```

Since your question refers to the basics of LaTeX understanding I would definitely recommend you to read one of the many LaTeX beginners guides and their chapters on debugging.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I compile, the reference for mybook does not appear in the pdf. I have the other two entries, but not the one referring to the book.

Comment: @Dario Solved it.